# How to export a a jar file correctly?

Tags: java, export, program-entry-point

I mean I tried to export my java game like this : EXPORT>Jar File but if I do this it doesn't start.

And if I export to executable jar file it doesn't export my resources into the jar file.

I mean if I play the game in eclipse the sound works. But if I export to executable jar file it doesn't work. I guess it is not exporting the sound too.

This is the code I tried to use to launch the jar file :

`java jar -cvfe ProjectZero.jar Main.Launcher Main.Launcher.class`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions for solving this problem, hope this is clear enough:

**Solution #1 - You want your resources outside of the JAR file**

Just copy/paste the folder containing your resources in the same folder containing the JAR file. (Make sure the directory matches pathes mentioned in the application.)

**Solution #2 - You want your resources inside the JAR file**

If you want the resources to be directly included in the JAR file, you could use the function getResource() to get the images/sounds. Then make sure that resources are visible in both: "/src" and "/bin" folders.

For example, if you have the following application code:

```
ImageIcon myIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/icon.gif"));
```

your file should be visible in:

```
/myApp/src/resources/icon.gif
/myApp/bin/resources/icon.gif
```

Then you can export your application as a JAR file, it will contain the resources.

Comment: it gives me an error.. Cannot instantiate JComponent().. i'm currently using eclipse so maybe that's a problem

Comment: and also setIcon(myIcon) is undefined for the type JComponent

Comment: @VerdesAndrei It does not matter using Eclipse or not. This piece of code was just an example. You should only pay attention to "this.getClass().getResource("/resources/icon.gif")" to retrieve the path of your resource.